# Finding a large rank positive semidefinte matrix *C* whose entries give rise to a singular matrix *L*

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, solver, determinants

**My goal in a nutshell:**

Given an 8x8 matrix *C* I have an algorithm which constructs another 8x8 matrix *L=L(C)* in physically relevant way, wherein each entry of *L* is given by a particular (possibly irrational) linear combination of up to 8 entries of *C*. I want to find a particular choice of *C* which is positive semidefinite and has large rank (7 or 8) but gives rise to a singular *L*.

**Facts:**

- Every positive semidefinite *C* can be written as *C=U*U* for some *U* (where *U** denotes the complex conjugate transpose of *U*).
- In this case *ker U=ker C*, and so the rank of *U* and *C* are the same.
- If *U* has a nonsingular 7x7 principle submatrix, then the rank of *U* is at least 7.

**Naive solution:**

1. Declare *U* as an 8x8 matrix of symbols and create *C=U*U*. This guarantees *C* is positive semidefinite.
2. Define *V* to be the upper-left 7x7 principle submatrix of *U*. Note if *V* is nonsingular the rank of *C* is at least 7.
3. Compute *L* from *C*.
4. Try to *solve([ det(V)~=0, det(L)==0 ], [vars])*, where vars=entries of *U*.

**The difficulty:**

One immediate problem is that not every choice of *U* which is rank 7 or 8 will have *V* nonsingular, so the matrix *C* I'm seeking might be missed in this regime. Ignoring this here, my issue for this forum is more to the complexity of the problem:

By setting *C=U*U* and using the entries of *U* as the variables, each entry of *C* becomes a sum of 8 terms, each degree 2. E.g., the c21 entry is given by

```
u11*conj(u12) + u21*conj(u22) + u31*conj(u32) + u41*conj(u42) + u51*conj(u52) + u61*conj(u62) + u71*conj(u72) + u81*conj(u82)
```

Since each entry of *L* is a linear combination of between 2 and 8 entries of *C*, we have that each entry of *L* is a linear combination of between 2*8=16 and 8*8=64 degree 2 terms from the entries of *U* (or *U**). Thus *det(L)* is a uniform degree 2*8=16 polynomial with between 8!*16^8≈10^14 and 8!*64^8≈10^19 terms before simplification. I need this polynomial to be zero while simultaneously *det(V)* is nonzero (a uniform degree 7 polynomial with 7!=5040 terms).

Note that if one were to avoid using *C=U*U* and instead let the entries of *C* be the variables, then *det(L)* would be a uniform degree 8 polynomial with between 8!*2^8≈10^7 and 8!*8^8≈10^11 terms before simplification. I would need this polynomial to be zero while simultaneously *det(V)* is nonzero and some extra conditions are placed so that *C* is positive semidefinite (Sylvester's Criterion, etc).

**My question:**

Is there a smarter way to do this? Certainly the determinant is not the most efficient way to determine if *L* is singular, but ideally I would like an exact answer for *C*, rather then a numerical approximation.

I am most familiar with Matlab, but any suggestions using any system (Python, Macaulay2, ...) would be *greatly* appreciated. For computing power, I have access to several supercomputer clusters.

**Edits:**

Perhaps a bit lofty a question. More digestible sub-questions:

- Is there a computationally easier, ideally symbolic, algorithm for determining if a matrix is singular (opposed to computing the determinant)?
- Is there a computationally easier way of demanding the answer be positive semidefinite (opposed to setting *C=U*U* and using the entries of *U* as the variables)?
- Is there a less restrictive (but still computationally easy) way to demand that *C* has rank 7 or 8?